# How to solve AWS Cognito - Login with Amazon "An unknown scope was requested" error?

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

**How do I solve the "An unknown scope was requested" error???**

I am trying to configure "Login with Amazon" as an AWS Cognito Identity Provider.

I have the "Cognito User Pool" working correctly, but when I try to sign in with Amazon through the Hosted UI, I get the following error:

```
>**Error Summary**
>
>400 Bad Request
>
>An unknown scope was requested
>
>**Request Details**
>
>client_id={client_id}
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F{domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com%2Foauth2%2Fidpresponse
scope=email
response_type=code
state=H4sIAAAAAAAAAG...
```

Please look at the images below and tell me what I'm missing.

Here are my Client App Settings:
[image]

Here are the Identity Provider Settings:
[image]

Here are the attribute mapping settings:
[image]

And here are my Amazon Developer "Security Profile" settings:
[image]

Comment: I changed `http://localhost:8080/login` to `https://{domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse`, and now when I click on "Continue with Login with Amazon" in the Hosted UI, it no longer shows the error page. It redirects me to my website, but with the following query parameters: `/?error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested%3B+error%3Dinvalid_scope&error=invalid_scope`. How do I get the `?code=` query parameter on the redirect?

Comment: I had this same issue and it now works after correcting the Allowed Return URLs to https://{YOUR_COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/idpresponse and using "profile" as the Authorize Scope as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while using passport. I added a scope field in AmazonStrategy.

```
 passport.use(
new AmazonStrategy(
  {
    clientID: process.env.AMAZON_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: '/auth/amazon/callback',
    scope: ['profile'],
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    UserDAO.getUser(profile.id)
      .then((user) => {
        if (user) {
        console.log('user found',user);
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          UserDAO.addUser({...profile, username: profile.id})
            .then((newUser) => {
              console.log('new user created',newUser);
              return done(null, {...profile, _id: newUser.insertedId, username: profile.id});
            })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err);
          });
          
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return done(err);
      });
  }
));
```

Now I am able to use login with amazon in my web app. Check the 7th line in my code where I added the scope field.